# Java Разница между сеттерами и конструктороми

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор, setter

В чем разница между сеттерами и конструктором помимо того что конструктор используется для создания экземпляра класса? Я имею в виду способность конструктора инициализировать поля почему не делать это сеттерами? А конструктор использовать для создания экземпляра?
В чем выгода использования сложных конструкторов?

Comment: а в чем смысл вызывать десяток сеттеров, вместо того, чтоб сделать это при помощи парочки конструкторов? причем один из них будет вызываться из другого.. в итоге написать `new Object(1,2,3,4,8,5,6,7,8)` проще чем пучок сеттеров, нет? Причем еще и поля если должны быть приватные, а сеттеры уже гарантируют изменение оных

Comment: Сеттер это способ "защиты", который ограничивает возможность других классов менять содержимое. Все конечно зависит от того какой уровень доступа.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, **конструктор инициализирует** все поля, включая защищенные и закрытые, которые недоступны для пользователей класса.

Во-вторых, **конструктор** позволяет создать объект в определенном **корректном** состоянии.

В-третьих, вы можете создавать так называемые **временные** объекты, которые не привязываются к конкретному идентификатору, а потому для таких объектов, фактически, невозможно вызвать несколько сеттеров.

В-четвертых, **один** вызов конструктора **заменяет** собой несколько вызовов сеттеров.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. Я в общем-то об этом догадывался... )))Но вот мысль о том что это необходимо для временных объектов где с сеттерами не получится это круто! Я под таким углом не смотрел на этот вопрос. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Павел Не за что. Удачи.:)

Answer (score 3):

*Конструкторы с параметрами* предназначены для инициализации полей объекта какими-либо **начальными** значениями.

*Сеттеры* же предназначены для инициализации (или изменения) полей объекта значениями, которые на момент создания объекта **неизвестны**.

И вообще, очевидно, что рациональнее сделать так:

```
Human human = new Human("John", 31);
```

чем так:

```
Human human = new Human();
human.setName("John");
human.setAge(31);
```

Зачем куча сеттеров, если можно создать объект с нужными параметрами одной строкой?...